# I have a 50 year old house that needs a new roof, existing is interlocking shingles. Roof is shiplap on a diagonal pattern, do i need to have plywood

Tags: roofing

Our 50 year old home has a shiplap roof base, do we need to add plywood before new shingles are applied?

Comment: Is the current roof deck "shiplap" or is it "skip sheathing"? What, exactly, are the "interlocking shingles" that you're replacing (just not a term I'm familiar with)? What kind of new roofing are you putting on? If you're putting on steel roofing, wood shakes, tile or slate, they have enough integrity to span any gaps in the sub roof. If you're putting on asphalt shingles, they need a contiguous base and won't tolerate any gaps or rotten spots. A picture of the existing roofing material and of the underside (from the attic) would be most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If the current roof deck is solid/not rotten, no need to add plywood.

If it's rotting out due to leaks, then replacement is going to be needed and plywood makes sense.

Dry wood in good shape does not have an expiration date. It's been doing the job for 50 years...